# Handlebar changes are not affecting - Python Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-cache

I am a django and python beginner. Django Application is hosted in apache webserver as daemon.
I am facing the issue with rendering the URL in django using java script.

In my handlebar(html template), i did some html changes, but, unfortunately changes have not been reflected.

Flow be like,
When calling and URL from browser, my urls.py will call views.py, inside the views.py , Node_edit.html will be renderred.

Node_edit.html will contains handlebar.

Sorry for my poor english.

views.py

@csrf_protect

def hierarchyNode_new(request, parentNode_id=None):

```
parentNodeObject = None

if(parentNode_id):

    context = {
        "parentNode_id": parentNode_id
    }
    return render(request, 'test/Node_edit.html', context)
```

Node_edit.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

```
    var assetList =
    [
       //applying the html template
       { url: '{% static "test/handlebar/Node.handlebar" %}', loadHandler: templateLoaderFunction, name: 'Node_edit'        },

    ]
    $(document).ready( function () {

        debug.log("load complete")

        registerHandlebarHelpers()

        // create templates hash if not already present
        Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};

        console.log(assetList);

        chainLoadAssets(assetList, function()

        {

            var hierarchyNodeEditor = new HierarchyNodeEditor(

                "{% url 'test:index' %}",
                "{% url 'test:Node_list' %}",
                {% if Node %}
                "{% url 'test:Node_jsonbase' %}",
                {% else %}
                "{% url 'test:Node_new' %}",
                {% endif %}
                "{{ Node.id }}",
                "{{ parentNode_id }}",
                "{{ csrf_token }}"
            )
            NodeEditor.start()
        })

    })

</script>
```

Node.handlebar

```
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Node_edit_display" checked="checked" (Trying to make check box checked)
            {{#ifeq json.display "1" }}
                checked
            {{/ifeq}}
        />
      </div>
```

Note: Even if i deleted that handlebar. But still the page is getting rendering. But issue, is my changes are not getting effect in browser

I cleared my  browser cache and restarted the apache.

Doubts:

Is there any other cache, i should clear ?

This is my stage server. 
But, this issue is not coming in my development server.

When applying the changes in stage server facing this problem.

Stil i have stuck in this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

**python manage.py collectstatic** should do the trick